# How can a small difference in input string cause a large difference in std::regex_search performance

Tags: regex, performance, multiline

How can the small change in the `command` string can cause such a large
performance difference. Is my regex wrong?
The intent is to extract the (possibly multiline string) between the two markers '|>'.
I compiled this code using Visual Studio and Microsoft C++ compiler.

```
    bool testCommandMatching() {
        const std::string group(R"(
                gcc 
                src\hello.c 
               -o bin\hello 
            )");
        const std::regex cmdRe(R"(^\|>((?:.*\s*)*)\|>)");
        bool bothMatched = true;
        {
            std::cmatch match;
            const std::string command(R"(|>
                gcc 
                src\hello.c 
               -o bin\hello 
            |>)");
            auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            bool matched = std::regex_search(command.c_str(), match, cmdRe, std::regex_constants::match_continuous);
            auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            // elapsed is less than 10 ms
            auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
            bothMatched = bothMatched && group == (matched ? match[1] : std::string(""));
        }
        {
            std::cmatch match;
            const std::string command(R"(|>
                gcc 
                src\hello.c 
               -o bin\hello 
            |> bin\hello)");
            auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            bool matched = std::regex_search(command.c_str(), match, cmdRe, std::regex_constants::match_continuous);
            auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            // elapsed is more than 1000 ms. How is this possible?
            auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
            bothMatched = bothMatched && group == (matched ? match[1] : std::string(""));
        }
        return bothMatched;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to match until the last occurrence `^\|>(.*(?:\r?\n.*)*)\|>`

Comment: PCRE Regexp can have an exponential execution time so one additional character in the input can more than double the performance. things like `.*.*.*` can cause that. You need to be careful about quantifiers because of this. Greedy/Lazy operators can sometime help in such a case but the best is to rewrite the regexp so to avoid such pattern. I think `(?:.*\s*)*` should be a problem in your regexp. Alternatively, you can use a Regexp library generating a deterministic automaton (e.g. Google's Re2) so the parsing is guaranteed to run in polynomial time (actually linear AFAIK).

Comment: [`(?:.*\s*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/WLA5dJ/1) (55307 steps) can be rewritten as the much faster [`[\S\s]*`](https://regex101.com/r/bMR9dh/1) (33 steps)

Comment: contrast second one [failing](https://regex101.com/r/bMR9dh/2) (226 steps) versus [original](https://regex101.com/r/WLA5dJ/2) (catastrophic backtracking)

Comment: [Russ Cox's series of articles](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) provides a thorough explanation

Comment: Thank you @jhnc, your regex solves the performance issue and Cox's article helped me understanding why it does so.

Comment: @jhnc: if you want something efficient, use an unrolled pattern with possessive quantifiers: https://regex101.com/r/QbwiIY/1 .

Comment: It's also possible to change the non-capturing group to an atomic group: [`(?>.*\s*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/ik7ILl/1)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks, I knew the possessive terminology but not atomic group. something to add to my toolbox